# Spamassassin - testing content of an html email with no headers

Tags: email, spamassasin

I'm using Scrivener to write emails for my business. I then use the "compile" feature to export to HTML.

I'm wondering if there is a way to use spam-assassin to do a local test on a folder with multiple html emails within it.

I would only be looking for testing of the subject line and the content of the email. So I don't want to fool with sending the email anywhere. Plus, the html files won't have email headers.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some SpamAssassin tests use the mail headers, so they're sort of required. At least, without them, your results will be a lot less accurate.

I'd suggest the easiest approach is to stuff the HTML documents into an email. This is pretty easy to do with a trivial shell script. Note this and the next example use `flip` (which you may have to install) to convert to email's CRLF line endings. You could also use `sed`, I suppose. Or maybe it's fine without it.

```
cat <<HEADER - in/message.html | flip -m > out/message.eml
From: "Your Company Name" <email@companyname.example.com>
To: "Your Name" <your-email@example.com>
Date: $(date -R)
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-transfer-encoding: binary
Subject: Your Subject Here

HEADER
```

Downside, that leaves you with a non-MIME HTML-only message. You may have to disable a SpamAssassin rule which will dock your message for being HTML-only.

Another option is the `mime-construct` utility, which again you may have to install. Then you'd do:

```shell
mime-construct --to '"Your Name" <your-email@example.com>' \
               --subject "Your Subject Here" \
               --header 'From: "Your Company Name" <email@companyname.example.com>' \
               --header "Date: $(date -R)" \
               --multipart 'multipart/alternative' --output \
               --type 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' --file in/message.txt \
               --type 'text/html; charset=utf-8' --file in/message.html \
    | flip -m - > out/message.eml
```

You could use `lynx -dump` to make your plain-text alternative (e.g., `lynx -dump in/message.html > in/message.txt`)

You should then be able to run the generated file through SpamAssassin as an email.

It should go without saying that you need to follow other email best practices (confirmed opt-in, easy ubsubscribe, etc.).